# How can I add two numbers using ejs(Embedded JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I want to add 2 numbers which is coming from the back end. I am trying to add 
using `<%=num1%> + <%=num2%>` but its printing num1num2 instead of num1+num2.
What I am doing wrong and what is alternative solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is done by

```
<%= num1 + num2 %>
```

What you are doing is only displaying the elements because when you have '<%=' this means to display this item.
Another way to do this can be.

```
// Add the numbers
<% var addedNumber = num1 + num2; %>
//Then display the added numbers
<%= addedNumber %>
```

Answer (score 0):

pass numbers to template from your controller.

```
res.render('index', { result: {n1:1,n2:2} });
```

and then in ejs template just like javascript

```
<%= n1+ n2 %>
```